# C function calls in C++ class namespace

Tags: c++, system-calls

I'm attempting to familiarize myself with C++ by way of a project, but I have hit an error that I am not quite sure how to deal with. I have the following code:

```
void myclass::write(std::string str) {
  write(filedes, (void *)str.c_str(), str.length());
}
```

Where filedes is an instance variable of myclass. Attempting to compile this yields the error:

```
myclass.cpp: In member function ‘void myclass::write(std::string)’:
myclass.cpp:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘myclass::write(int&, void*, size_t)’
myclass.cpp:37: note: candidates are: void myclass::write(std::string)
myclass.hpp:15: note:                 void myclass::write(std::string, int)
```

So what am I doing wrong? Can I not legally make this function call from the method?

Comment: why are you casting `c_str` to void*? the compiler doesn't find which function you're trying to call

Comment: The write system call takes a void* as an argument.

Comment: put `::` before `c` function to determine that you want the function from the global namespace ... `::write(filedes, (void *)str.c_str(), str.length())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably you want to call `write(2)`, which is in the global namespace:

```
::write(filedes, str.c_str(), str.length());
```

(you might need to `#include <unistd.h>`).

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I wasn't sure how to refer to the "global namespace". Thanks! Accepting your answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the compiler isn't aware of a global `write` function. Did you include the right headers (`<unistd.h>` in unix)? (Also, that `(void *)` cast is useless.)

Comment: This wouldn't matter. The way name lookup works means that the member functions are found first and the search stops there.

Answer (score 0):

filedes is not an instance variable of your class (not an instance of your class), but a member of your class with type int, as I see from the compiler error. If you want to call a function from a global namespace with the same name as a method there, use ::write(...). By the way: Use std::size_t for length, not int.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler thinks that write is your class method and it isnt. If you are talking about system call write you should #include unistd.h and use ::write(filedes, (void *)str.c_str(), str.length());

Answer (score 0):

it depends what is the write function if it is a system function then you have to use 
::write , if it is in some other code make sure you put extern, use the header or the code that implements the function